# Set wallpaper from file path

Tags: java, android, file, path, wallpaper

I have found plenty of details on how to set a wallpaper from a drawable etc however is it possible to do this from a file location.

I have confirmed that the following code prints out the location of the file

```
Toast.makeText(MyWallpapers.this, "" + listFile[position].getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

String ImageLocation = listFile[position].getAbsolutePath();
```

And so I have been trying something like this to get it to set the wallpaper.

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(ImageLocation);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it doesn't like it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file into a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) and call [WallpaperManager.setBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)